# Adding mocks to sets works with .times, not with for loop

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, spock

We've come across a very peculiar behaviour with mocks and sets in Spock.

In a Spock (0.5, Groovy 1.7) `given:` block (`amount` is an `Integer`):

```
Set<Operand> operands=new HashSet<Operand>()
for (index in amount){
  operand = Mock(Operand)
  operand.update() >> null
  operands.add(operand)
}
```

After each loop run (breakpoint on closing bracket), there's only one (1) element in the set, when the loop starts anew, `operands.size() == 0`. Apparently, the mock objects mysteriously disappear.

In the following version, everything works and the set has `operands.size() == amount` after the loop runs.

```
Set<Operand> operands=new HashSet<Operand>()
amount.times{
  operand = Mock(Operand)
  operand.update() >> null
  operands.add(operand)
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why the first version does not work?

Comment: Which version of Spock are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. Edited. 0.5/1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to Spock (and `Set`s). `for (index in amount)` is simply not a correct way to write a loop with `amount` iterations in Groovy. After `in`, Groovy expects something that it knows how to iterate over (e.g. an `Iterable`). The fallback is to (logically) treat an object as a collection containing just itself. This explains why you get just one iteration where `index == amount`.

The shortest way to write a loop with `amount` iterations is `amount.times {}`, as in your second snippet.

Comment: Or `for( index in 1..amount )`